# Rails routing for daily exercise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So right now I have a model called exercise and response. In my route, I have

```
resources :exercise, param: :title do
    resources :response
end
```

I'm trying to rewrite the url so that when users visit /daily-exercise, it will bring up the same view used for `/exercise/:title/responses/new` but the url on the browser will still be `/daily-exercise`. Does anyone know a way to do this?

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention this but the exercise changes everyday so I would have to map the url to a different action such as `exercises#daily_exercise`

Comment: And where would the ID for title come from?

Comment: I'm using friendlyId gem to add a slug to the column of Exercise model and the title will be used as a slug. So, I find a exercise like the following,          exercise = Exercise.where("slug = ?", params[:title]). Then, I get the id with exercise.id

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But `params[:title]` won't exist when you go to `/daily-exercise`.

Comment: I have an action in the ExercisesController called daily_exercise that basically redirects to `/exercise/:title/responses/new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Create a new custom route that maps to your #show action in the exercises controller:

```
get '/daily-excercise', to: ' responses#show'
```

The problem is you need a way to pull in the parameter for the excercise of the day. You could set this programmatically and ignore pull in an ID if it's on a daily basis in your controller.

```
before_filter :define_exercise, only: :new

def define_exercise
  if request.fullpath.match(/daily-exercise/)
    @excercise = Excercise.find_by_exercise 
  else
    @exercise.find(params[:title])
  end
end
```

As was mentioned, if you need to pass in the id as a param:

```
get '/:title/daily-excersise', to: 'responses#show'
```

Conversely, create another controller action #daily_exercise, but this isn't very RESTful.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: Not correct. @klchoi wanted a `new` `response`, not to `show` an `exercise`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what he wants. I assumed he wants a partial form for /exercise/:title/responses/new view on exercises#show